# A example of a Hausdorff space that is normal space but not paracompact

Tags: general-topology

I need your help. Can anyone give me a example of Hausdorff space that is normal but not paracompact.
Thanks for you help.

Comment: this link may be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29

Comment: For those not aware of [this wonderful resource](https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=hausdorff%20%2B%20normal%20%2B~Paracompact) I would highly recommend it!

Answer (score 1):

The ordinal space $\omega_1$ in the order topology is not paracompact, but it is hereditarily normal and Hausdorff and countably paracompact.

[$\pi$-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%24T_4%24%2B%7EParacompact) has some more (e.g. the long line, which is related) and Bing's space $G$ and subspaces of it.